# Short story: alien transporter technology extinguishes the soul

Tags: story-identification, teleportation, souls

This is from a dystopian anthology I read in the early 1970's.

Humans encounter a friendly alien race that shares advanced technologies. The protagonist's daughter (maybe) begs him to not use the Star Trek-style transporter. It seems harmless -- he uses it and so do most other people.  Later they they learn the transporter kills off the person's creativity / spark / soul -- and that the alien culture has become insipid / barren from this effect.

This was NOT the Slabscape books (first published in 2010).  I read this in the early 1970s.

Comment: Probably the same story I'm looking for from https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220287/short-story-where-aliens-teleportation-technology-doesnt-transmit-the-soul although I don't have much information to provide since it was a secondhand query. It might be useful to know that the narrator may be a reporter.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.